# How to prove by induction that $10^n = 3m+1$

Tags: polynomials, induction

Let $n∈ℕ_0$ and $m∈ℕ_0$. Show that $10^n = 3m+1$.

You can clearly see that for $n=0$, $m=0$ and $n=1$, $m=3$ and $n=2$, $m=33$ ... $n$ is the number of how many times a 3 is added to $m$ like $n=5$, then $m$ has to be $33333$ (five three's). But how to show that by induction? I always have problem to show something in a correct mathematical way...

Comment: Can you start writing out the induction?  What is the base case?  What do you assume for the inductive case?  What do you want to prove for the inductive case?

Comment: Have you learned about modulos?

Comment: @Rushabh Do you mean the rest of a division like 7%3=1?

Comment: @Michael Burr Base Case is showing it for a n=0 or another number. Inductive case would be to show it for n+1 (for any n)

Comment: The inductive assumption is quite important in the inductive step.  What is the inductive hypothesis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To proceed by induction we have

- base case: $n=0 \implies 10^0=1=3\cdot 0+1$
- induction step: assume $10^n=3m+1$ true (Ind. Hyp.) we want to show that $10^{n+1}=3s+1$

then we have

$$10^{n+1}=10\cdot 10^n \stackrel{Ind. Hyp.}= 10 \cdot (3m+1)=$$$$=30m+10=30m+9+1=3(10m+3)+1=3s+1$$

Comment: Is it normal to give the variable a new name (from m to s) ? I think I understand now how it should work: 1. Base Case n=0. 2. Inductive step n+1 and with these step and the assumption we show it for all n's

Comment: @D.Dave Yes the meaning here is to prove that any $10^n$ has remainder $1$ whan divided by $3$.

Comment: Oh, thank you for your answer!

Comment: @D.Dave You are welcome! Do not hesitate to ask for any other doubts about that!

Answer (score 7):

You don't need induction for this:$$10^n-1=(9+1)^n-1=9^n+\binom n19^{n-1}+\binom n29^{n-2}+\cdots+\binom n{n-1}9,$$which is a multiple of $3$.

Comment: This question is a standard induction example question from intro to proof, so it's likely that the OP would like to see how such an approach works out (even though this works).

Comment: @MichaelBurr The OP seems to think that to prove this in a mathematical way is the same thing as proving it by induction. I meant to explain that **it is not** the same thing.

Comment: I meant by induction, sorry for the unclarity - Question edited but thx for another mathematical perspective !

Answer (score 3):

You can prove it also like this (without induction)

$$10^k-1 = (10-1)(\underbrace{10^{k-1}+10^{k-2}+...+10+1}_m)=9m$$

so you easyl get a stronger result, that is $$10^k=9m+1$$

Comment: Thank you for new ideas!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$10^{n+1}=10 \cdot 10^n =10 \cdot (3m+1)=30 m+10= 3\cdot (10 m+3)+1$$

Comment: Also thanks for your hint!